# Manually building a Kernel source from Yocto build

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto

I have a Yocto build for i.mx6 and I want to modify its Kernel. I figured that if I copy Kernel source outside the Yocto project and make my modifications without dealing with patches, I can speed things up significantly. But the thing is, the Kernel source I have to use is already patched and I want to fetch and continue working from there. I will work on the already-patched source files and re-arranging them is a painful process.

For starting point, my patches work fine, and I can get a working image using `bitbake fsl-image-multimedia-full` command. The Kernel source I want to use is created after this process.

I have tried copying the source under `..../tmp/work-shared/imx6qsabresd/kernel-source`. Although `make zImage` and `make modules` finished without any trouble, manual building was not successful with an error in a dtsi file (Unable to parse...). Of course, I have checked the file and there was no syntax error.

Also, I checked the kernel source files I copied and it seems that the patches are successfully implemented.

Am I doing something wrong with the patches? With my manual build routine, I can build unpatched kernel source with no errors. I am sure that there are experienced Yocto users here that have their own workarounds to make this process shorter. So, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite method of doing kernel development in a Yocto project is to create an SDK and build the kernel outside of the Yocto system.  This allows more rapid builds because `make` will only build new changes, whereas a kernel build within Yocto always starts from scratch.

Here are some of my notes on compiling the Linux kernel outside of the Yocto system.  The exact paths for this will depend on your exact configuration and software versions.  In your case, `IMAGE_NAME=fsl-image-multimedia-full`

1. Run `bitbake -c populate_sdk ${IMAGE_NAME}`. You will get a
   self-extracting and self-installing shell script.
2. Run the shell script (for me it was
   `tmp/deploy/sdk/${NAME}-glibc-i686-${IMAGE_NAME}-cortexa9hf-neon-toolchain-1.0.0.sh`),
   and agree to the default SDK location (for me it was
   `usr/local/oecore-i686`).
3. Source the scripts generated by the install script.  I use the
   following helper script to load the SDK so I don't have to keep
   track of the paths involved.  You need to source this in each time
   you want to use the SDK.

**enable_sdk.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]
then
    echo "Error: you must source this script."
    exit 1
fi
source /usr/local/oecore-i686/environment-setup-corei7-32-${NAME}-linux
source /usr/local/oecore-i686/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-${NAME}-linux-gnueabi
```

4. Copy the `defconfig` file from your Yocto directory to your kernel
   directory (checked out somewhere outside of the Yocto tree) as
   `.config`.
5. Run `make oldconfig` in your kernel directory so that the Linux
   kernel build system picks up the existing `.config`.

   Note: you may have to answer questions about config options that
   are not set in the `.config` file.

   Note: running `make menuconfig` will fail when the SDK is enabled,
   because the SDK does not have the `ncurses` libraries set up
   correctly. For this command, run it in a new terminal that has not
   enabled the SDK so that it uses the local ncurses-dev packages you
   have installed.
6. Run `make -jN` to build the kernel.
7. To run the new kernel, copy the `zImage` and `${NAME}.dtb` files to
   your NFS/TFTP share or boot device.  I use another script to speed
   up the process.

**update_kernel.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo cp /path-to-linux-source/arch/arm/boot/dts/${NAME}.dtb /srv/nfs/${DEVICE}/boot/
sudo cp /path-to-linux-source/arch/arm/boot/zImage /srv/nfs/${DEVICE}/boot/
set +x
```

8. You can also point Yocto to your local Linux repo in your `.bb`
   file.  This is useful for making sure your kernel changes still
   build correctly within Yocto.

   `SRC_URI = "git:///path-to-linux-source/.git/;branch=${KBRANCH};protocol=file"`

UPDATE: Over a year later, I realize that I completely missed the question about broken patches.  Without more information, I can't be sure what went wrong copying the kernel source from Yocto to an external build.  I'd suggest opening a Bitbake devshell for the kernel and doing a diff with the external directory after manually applying patches to see what went wrong, or just copy the source from inside the devshell to your external directory.
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.4.2/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#platdev-appdev-devshell

> When debugging certain commands or even when just editing packages, devshell can be a useful tool. **When you invoke devshell**, source files are extracted into your working directory and **patches are applied**.

Answer (score 4):

You can also edit files in `tmp/work-shared/<machine>/kernel-source` then compile modified kernel with  `bitbake -C compile virtual/kernel`

Answer (score 0):

Since it can't parse it, there seems to be a problem with patch. How do you patch the device tree? Are you patching it in the .bb file?

If so, check your patch for possible syntax errors, it's very easy to overlook the syntax errors in device tree. You can remove the patch and do it manually from `bitbake -c devshell <kernel-name>`

If not, please try to do it there and check again. Please share results if any of these helps you.

Comment: I have check the supposedly erroneous dts file many times. Shouldn't `bitbake fsl-image-multimedia-full` return error if there is something wrong with the patches anyway? Process completes successfully, and when I check the image on my system, I see that the patches are applied successfully. By the way, I have a layer for my custom board, and I use .bbappend files for patching.